# Please turn off auto complete for text box in close as duplicate dialog

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, close-dialog

When voting to close as duplicate, my browser auto completes past values in the text box:

[image: auto complete of past duplicate targets]

While I know this is "my fault" and I can manually clear those values, it would be neat if the text box could get `autocomplete="off"` attribute, thus nullifying the issue. The chance I'll need to use a past value there is very small anyway. It's just another click I need to make before I can actually close.

Comment: So now we know your favorite duplicate targets ...

Comment: [Please, no!](https://xkcd.com/1172/) This is quite useful for me. Whenever I need to close another `Cannot read property of document.getElementById(…)` question, I just type `not find` in the duplicate box to get to [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212).